# UWP ListView in touch mode

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have this ListView in a Windows 10 project:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemsList, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BindableSourceConverter}}"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
              RelativePanel.Below="pageHeader"
              CanReorderItems="True" 
              SelectionMode="None"
              CanDragItems="True"
              AllowDrop="True"
              CanDrag="True" />
```

and i need to allow the user to reorder the ListView.

Using mouse everything works fine, but using the touch, i need to wait one second before that i'm able to move the items around.

Any idea on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any, if you don't wait one second internal ScrollViewer thinks you do scroll action. Since it can't know your intention for sure, it can't know the difference.

If you don't need scroll action, consider not using ListView.

Comment: Thanks, i need to reorder 4 elements, any suggestion?

Comment: Only way I can think of is to implement reorder manually, through Manipulation[Started/Delta/Completed] events. You will need to track position of manipulated item and move others out of the way accordingly. I understand it's a bit complicated; perhaps there are some better ways to achieve that.